# How to fix this error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'String or binary data would be truncated.' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

My Table :-

```
ID  int Unchecked
ColName varchar(255)    Unchecked
Title   varchar(255)    Unchecked
DataSource  varchar(255)    Checked
ControlID   int Unchecked
MaxLength   int Unchecked
Width   int Unchecked
Height  int Unchecked
IsMandatory bit Unchecked
CommandArea char(1) Checked
CreatedBy   int Checked
CreatedOn   datetime    Checked
UpdatedOn   datetime    Checked
Status  bit Checked
UpdatedBy   int Checked
IPAddress   varchar(1)  Checked
```

My stored-procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spaddvoucherreachcols] @xml   XML,
                                              @error VARCHAR(1000) output
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
          INSERT INTO VoucherReachCols
                      (ColName,
                       Title,
                       DataSource,
                       ControlID,
                       MaxLength,
                       Width,
                       Height,
                       IsMandatory,
                       CreatedBy,
                       CreatedOn,
                       UpdatedOn,
                       Status,
                       UpdatedBy,
                       IPAddress)
          SELECT N.value('(Title)[1]', 'Varchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(ColName)[1]', 'Varchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(DataSource)[1]', 'Varchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(ControlID)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(MaxLength)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(Width)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(Height)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(IsMandatory)[1]', 'Varchar(MAX)'),
                 N.value('(CreatedBy)[1]', 'int'),
                 Getdate(),
                 Getdate(),
                 1,
                 N.value('(UpdatedBy)[1]', 'int'),
                 N.value('(IPAddress)[1]', 'Varchar(20)')
          FROM   @XML.nodes('/Table/VoucherReachCols') AS T(N);
      END TRY

      BEGIN CATCH
          SET @Error = Error_number() + ' ' + Error_message();
      END CATCH
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. Try replacing

```
N.value('(ControlID)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
N.value('(MaxLength)[1]', 'NVarchar(MAX)'),
```

with

```
N.value('(ControlID)[1]', 'int'),
N.value('(MaxLength)[1]', 'int'),
```

EDIT: Check source table: IPAddress   varchar(1) - in the actual insert I notice an IPAddress of varchar(20). You should alter table and increase this column width.

Comment: Also, N.value('(IsMandatory)[1]', 'Varchar(MAX)') ==> N.value('(IsMandatory)[1]', 'bit')

Comment: @NishantChauhan, what about increasing IPAddress column width? I edited the answer..